# Why do I receive the TypeError: "int" is not subscriptable error all of a sudden? It worked before I included a chi-square test in Kaggle notebook

Tags: pandas, seaborn, kaggle

I am trying to code a visualization in a Kaggle notebook. It involves graphing variables from a .csv file in distribution plots. I keep receiving the TypeError: "int" is not subscriptable.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(12,12))
sns.histplot(df['Satisfaction'], kde=True, ax = ax[0,0])
plt.ylabel("Count")
sns.histplot(df['Performance_evaluation'], kde=True, ax = ax[0,1])
sns.histplot(df['Monthly_hours'], kde=True, ax = ax[1,0])
```

TypeError: 'int object is not subscriptable (referring to line 2)

I've tried to look up articles on the error but not quite understanding what the issue is. I am new to Python.

Turns out, I defined df as degrees of freedom in my chi square test. Once I fixed that, there were no issues. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe `df` us an integer and not a dataframe? It's hard to tell without reproducible code.

Comment: When you did your chi square test, did you reassign `df` to be the degrees of freedom of the test?

Comment: Yes mwaskom, I reassigned df to be the degrees of freedom of the test! It resolved when I made the changes. Thank you so much. I'm trying to figure out how to mark your answer as correct.